# ParameterizedAssertionError in JUnit Theory

Tags: java, junit

The following test throws a ParameterizedAssertionError.
It seems that both parameters of the test method get the same argument, although they are of different types.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.junit.experimental.theories.DataPoint;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.DataPoints;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theory;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Theories.class)
    public class ErrorIDsTest {

    @DataPoints
    public static Field[] errorIDs() {
        return ErrorIDs.class.getDeclaredFields();
    }

    @DataPoint
    public static ResourceBundle bundle = null;

    @Theory
    public void testThatFails(Field field, ResourceBundle bundle) throws Exception {
    }

    interface ErrorIDs {
      public final String Fehler = "ErrorIDs.Fehler";
    }
}
```

The exception is `ParameterizedAssertionError`

> org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError:
>   testThatFails(errorIDs[0], errorIDs[0]) at
>   org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories$TheoryAnchor.reportParameterizedError(Theories.java:183)
>   at
>   org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories$TheoryAnchor$1$1.evaluate(Theories.java:138)
>   ...

I used an example from here [ParameterizedAssertionError in Theory](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/379) but facing exactly the same. It's fixed but I'm not using the same `.jar`. Is there any other fix to resolve this?